# Loosely coupled architecture (UI layer to BL Layer)

Tags: c#-4.0

Can anyone please explain to me, with the aid of sample code, about implementing a loosely coupled architecture in C#?

For example I have a Employee class in UI layer. In my DTO (model) project I created Name and age properties. I am creating object of BAL and calling GetEmployeeDetails() method. In BL I am calling appropriate method in DAL to get the EmployeeDetails.

Now I want to implement loosely coupled implementation between UI and BAL and BAL to DAL. I came to know that putting interfaces and getting the references would solve the problem. But in which layer should I implement interfaces? (I mean should I create a separate project for interfaces). Kindly explain with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

What about this article, which explained 3-Tier Architecture in asp.net using c# with a great example as below:

```
1) UI or Presentation Layer
2) Business Access Layer or Business Logic Layer
3) Data Access Layer
```

http://nice-tutorials.blogspot.com/2010/10/3-tier-architecture-in-aspnet-using-c.html

Comment: Hi AvAvkashChauhan
  Thanks for your reply. But I know the layer architecture and we are implementing the multi tier architecture in our office. From the example from the URL you have given,    they are accessing the method of BAL directly from UI layer. But my aim is the UI part should not know the methods or classes which are in BAL. I need to implement interface. But I am confused whether should I implement a separate project for that or should i append it before each BAL class.

Comment: I would prefer to have included that in BAL class if you want UI to not know what is in BAL.

Answer (score 0):

We are also implementing loosely coupled architecture only. We are implementing our interface like this..
.
UI >> BAL Interface  >> BAL >> DAL Interface >> DAL.

Each layer (Interface,BAL,DAL) is a separate project.

And to connect from UI to BAL and BAL to DAL we implementing "Spring.net" framework.
It works very lightly and performance is good.
There is plenty of information out there. I suggest a Google to learn more about the spring.net framework. It is mainly for loosely coupled architecture.